# Information Criterion SVM

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm

I've seen some papers providing Information Criterion for SVM (e.g. Demyanov, Bailey, Ramamohanarao & Leckie (2012)). But it doesn't seem like there is any implementation of such a method in Python. For instance, Sklearn only provides methods for linear models and random forest/gradien boosting algorithms.

Is there any implementation of a potential Information Criterion for SVM in Python?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SVM with changing the kernel for non-linear model.
For example, `kernel='poly'`.

Comment: Thanks, I've considered this idea, or simply using linear SVM, but ideally, I'd like to let the hyper-parameter tunning phase handling the choice of the kernel instead of forcing it. If their is no other option, I guess that it would be the best choice though.